# Android ArrayAdapter IndexOutOfBoundsException invalid Index

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, indexoutofboundsexception

This is a problem that I had fixed before by overriding the `getCount()` method like so:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
  return this.items.size();
}
```

But the problem has reappeared...I have a an ArrayList whose size is 12 but, the index should be from 0 to 11 but for some reason it keeps trying to index 12...

Do I need to change my `getCount()` implementation?

I had also overridden the `getItem()` but to no avail.

Comment: If you have 12 items in an `ArrayList` then the size is 12 - as simple as that...end of story. The index may go from 0 to 11 but that doesn't stop the size being 12. Without seeing further code it's impossible to come up with an answer.

Comment: have you debug the size of items in adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either override both `getCount` and `getItem` or none as they have to access the same list.

You may try this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return this.items.size();
};

@Override
public Site getItem(final int position) {
   return this.items.get(position);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this...but the problem still persists.

Comment: while updating your `ArrayAdapter` did you try `yourAdapter.clear();` and then `notifyDataSetChanged();`?